# numpy matmul gives weirdly wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

How do I understand the following? Per documentation a @ b is supposed to be the conventional matrix multiplication when both a and b is 2d array.

```py
>>> np.arange(20).reshape((2,10)) @ np.eye(10)
array([[ 9.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  5.,  8.,  9.],
       [29., 12., 14., 16.,  0., 11., 13., 15., 18., 19.]])
```

Why is it not just the transpose of the following

```py
>>> np.eye(10) @ np.arange(20).reshape((10,2))
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.],
       [ 8.,  9.],
       [10., 11.],
       [12., 13.],
       [14., 15.],
       [16., 17.],
       [18., 19.]])
```

Comment: I get `[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
 [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]]` for the first one.

Comment: `A@eye()` doesn't change `A`, so the problem isn't with `matmul`.  Look at the two reshape results by themselves.